# Postgresql - in a function after a trigger a NULL column makes all payload void

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I've a table with various columns - some of them can be NULL (there is no default value for them).

So I've created a trigger and each time I've a new value inserted in the table I want to trigger a `pg_notify`. (Hint: I'm a total noob about SQL).

The problem is that if just one of the column that can be null have a void value, then all the payload emitted by `pg_notify` is null.

A really simple example:

```
postgres=# create table example(id serial, name varchar); 
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create function new_example()  RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
PERFORM pg_notify('example', 'id: ' || NEW.id || ' name: ' || NEW.name);
RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# create trigger new_ex AFTER INSERT ON example FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE new_example();
CREATE TRIGGER
postgres=# LISTEN example;
LISTEN
postgres=# INSERT into example(name) VALUES ('a');
INSERT 0 1
Asynchronous notification "example" with payload "id : 1 name: a" received from server process with PID 22349.
```

This is correct - I've inserted a new row and the notify is exactly what I expect

```
postgres=# INSERT into example(name) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT 0 1
Asynchronous notification "example" received from server process with PID 22349.
```

This does not make any sense. I would expect something like `Asynchronous notification "example" with payload "id : 1 name: NULL" received from server process with PID 22349.` or `Asynchronous notification "example" with payload "id : 1 name:" received from server process with PID 22349.`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are concatenating strings with `||` operator and any of the argument is `NULL` then the entire expression evaluates to `NULL`.

To get around that use `CONCAT()` function that handles `NULL` values by simply removing them from string.

So, to the code:

```
PERFORM pg_notify('example', CONCAT('id: ', NEW.id, ' name: ', NEW.name));
```

This will however leave the following message to be empty, so you may want to use  `COALESCE()` function and come up with some fancy string that will tell you the value is really `NULL` and not a "null" string for example. One way to do that would be:

```
PERFORM pg_notify('example', CONCAT('id: ', NEW.id, ' name: ', COALESCE(NEW.name, '[#NULL#]')));
```

But you would still not distinguish string `[#NULL#]` from a real null value because they would look the same in the message returned from `NOTIFY`. See below for different approach.

---

Personally, I'd probably go within a slightly different approach by creating an audit table and inserting ids with schema and table name and this would serve your purpose for multiple tables checking for null values in various columns.

Comment: Thank you very much - actually the notification it will be used by a nodejs application, so I think I'll go with `COALESCE(NEW.description, '')` and I'll consider the `''` as NULL on nodejs side